# How to sort JSON by a single integer field?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sorting

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    title: 'title',
    ...,
    order: 0
}, {
    ...,
    order: 9
}, {
    ...,
    order: 2
}
```

...  the JSON includes many fields, how can I sort them based on the **order** field?

I was looking for something build into nodejs but I couldn't find anything that might be useful for that case.

Comment: That's not JSON. It looks like it's the inside of an array initializer. Are you working with **text** (e.g., JSON), or **objects** (e.g., the result of evaluating an array initializer)?

Comment: `arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a.order - b.order; })` - that was hard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At first, your need valid JSON, like that:

```
var unsorted = {
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Book",
            "order": 0
        },
        {
            "title": "Movie",
            "order": 9
        },
        {
            "title": "Cheese",
            "order": 2
        }
    ]
};
```

Afterwards you can easily sort the `items` and store them in a list.

```
var sorted = unsorted.items.sort(function(a, b) {return a.order - b.order});
```

Comment: this worked fine, but i needed to sort it in desc order, so i changed inner function to return: return b.order - a.order;

Answer (score 1):

A quick way would be to use a library like underscore.js - it's got a lot of functions that help you do exactly this kind of manipulation with JSON objects.

I've not tested this, but something along these lines:

```
_.sortBy(yourJSONdata, function(obj){ return +obj.order });
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6eQbp/2/

You can use the `Array.sort()` method to do the sorting.

Ref: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml